# What is the definition of "Serviceware"?

Tags: meaning

What is the definition of "[Serviceware](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Serviceware_in_the_Los_Angeles_County_Museum_of_Art)"? I guess it's the same thing as "Serveware"? On Wikipedia, "Serveware" redirects to "[Tableware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableware)".

If I would have to guess, I would say that "Tableware" refers to the items used by the client of a restaurant, while the Serviceware/Serveware refers to the items used both by client and by the waitress for bringing the food to the client (like for example trays, food serving carts etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find no references to this, but having done 'silver service' in my younger days, I would call the entire contents of a table (including the flowers and the tablecloth) the 'tableware'.

'Serviceware' I would confine to that which is used in service, hence the cutlery and the crockery, or 'plateware'.

The server serves a hot plate, and then uses cutlery to place food on the plate for the customer.

Comment: Thanks. And then the Serviceware is a subset of Tableware? And where would you place the trays, food serving carts and other items used by the waitress to bring the food and to arrange the table and the food?

Comment: @Fructibus  The whole caboodle would be 'kitchenware', I would say.

Comment: I just found that [plate stands](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Plate_stands) are named "serviceware" - their use is probably to help the guests to serve food while not at the table, therefore it's not tableware.

Comment: @Fructibus Trust the guests to muck it all up and confuse things. Guests are supposed to sit there quietly while they are served. The staff get no tips if the guests are all busy doing the job themselves !

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [extract](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Serviceware.-a0202661139) *servicesware* appears to be an evolution and a more comprehensive term than tableware,  in that it involves design  and innovation:

> - A painter would be lost without his canvas in much the same way a chef would be helpless without serviceware. ***It is the common denominator uniting all restaurant kitchens as it serves to bridge the space between customer and chef.***
> - ***Modern serviceware reflects, and in many cases defines, the identity of a restaurant and the personality of its chef***. The humble plate, fork, knife and spoon have existed for centuries, ***but contemporary serviceware designers are reinterpreting these staples in innovative ways.***  Their exquisite designs transcend utilitarian purpose as they delights excite and in some cases even shock the restaurant guest. Art Culinaire spoke with three of the field's most innovative Designers.

(Thefreelibrary.com)